# Is it possible to add dolby digital after Windows 10 warranty expires?

Tags: ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

Dolby digital is wanted to utilized in Ubuntu.

I wonder when it comes.

According to Wikipedia

License

Audio codec AC3 is covered by patents (though these are now expired[31]). Patents are used to ask to pay a commercial license to publish an application that decodes AC3. This leads some audio app developers to ban AC3 from their apps, although the open source VLC media player supports AC-3 audio without having paid for any kind of patent license.[32]

In Dolby's 2005 original and amended S-1 filings with the SEC, Dolby acknowledged that "Patents relating to our Dolby Digital technologies expire between 2008 and 2017."[33][34][35]

The last patent covering AC-3 expired March 20, 2017, so it is now generally free to use.[36]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Digital

Comment: Ask the providers of Dolby Digital if they ever plan a Linux version.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats